# Avoid recursive AOP

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I have an Aspect that intercepts a method a() decorated with the annotation @Foo. This method
calls another method b() also decorated with the annotation @Foo. I want my aspect to intercept
only a() and not b(). How can I do this?

I have tried within() but with no success. With ThreadLocal it works but I am wondering
if there is a Spring solution.

```
@Component
@Order(value = 2)
@Aspect
public class FooAspect {

   @Around(value = "@annotation(Foo)")
   public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Foo foo) {
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what your use-case is?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do that with Aspects only. The interception will happen no matter what.

However, one solution is to use a `ThreadLocal` `Byte` to flag that you've already applied the advice.

```
private ThreadLocal<Byte> flag = new ThreadLocal<>();

@Around(value = "@annotation(Foo)")
public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Foo foo) throws Throwable {
    if (flag.get() == null) {
        try {
            flag.set((byte) 1); // or 0, whatever
            // apply advice
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            flag.remove();
        }
    } else {
        // don't apply advice
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

You'll need to `catch` or `throws` the `Throwable` thrown from `proceed()`.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios for the answer; actually this is what I have done but I was wondering if there is a more clear solution like a proper AOP regular expression

Comment: @MikeArgyriou I doubt it. AOP doesn't have a stack-like feature for the matched join points that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `cflow` like `poincut` in the framework, but it's not supported by Aspectj-style.

However you can use it with aop-schema configuration approach.

For example:

```
public class NotInFlowPoincut extends  AspectJExpressionPointcut {

    private ControlFlowPointcut cflow;
    private Class<?> flowClass;
    private String methodName;

    public NotInFlowPoincut() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cflow = new ControlFlowPointcut(flowClass, methodName);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Method method, Class targetClass, Object[] args) {
        return super.matches(method, targetClass, args) && ! cflow.matches(method, targetClass, args);
    }

    public Class<?> getFlowClass() {
        return flowClass;
    }

    public void setFlowClass(Class<?> flowClass) {
        this.flowClass = flowClass;
    }

    public String getMethodName() {
        return methodName;
    }

    public void setMethodName(String methodName) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

}

public class FooAspect {

     public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Foo foo) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("in aroundAdvice");
            return pjp.proceed();
       }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
         A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
         a.a();

         B b = ctx.getBean(B.class);
         b.b();
     }

}

public class A {
    @Autowired B b;

    @Foo
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("In a()");
        b.b();
    }
}

public class B {

    @Foo
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("In b()");
    }

}
```

And finally

```
<bean id="cflow" class="test.NotInFlowPoincut">
    <property name="expression" value="@annotation(foo) " />
    <property name="methodName" value="aroundAdvice" />
    <property name="flowClass" value="test.FooAspect" />
</bean>

<bean id="foo" class="test.FooAspect" />

<bean id="a" class="test.A" />
<bean id="b" class="test.B" />

<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:aspect ref="foo" >
        <aop:around method="aroundAdvice" pointcut-ref="cflow" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Will output:

```
in aroundAdvice
In a()
In b()
in aroundAdvice
In b()
```

That seems to be what you are looking for.

Note that cflow poincut is slow, see javadoc.